# python recursive directory reading

Tags: python

I wish to avoid os.walk, i am using a recursive function to read files and folders and store files to a dictionary

I got rid of the os.chdir but for some reason function is now joining path + file as well and its generating an error :
WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid: 'c:\data\foo\notes\*.*'
Its reading folder foo and it joined path whit foo and file notes.txt instad of foo + libary folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212643/python-recursive-folder-read look like something for you

Comment: why dont you want os.walk?. It is specifically there for this purpose. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well if you are still learning os.walk gives you nothing if you want to understand how things work. For instance in C and Java i had no such thing as os.walk so i had to implement it by recursive functions.

Comment: that's fair enough. please check my answer

Comment: be aware that you can hit a recursion limit in Python.  Seeing how ``os.walk`` avoids that is intersting too... ``print( inspect.getsource(os.walk)) ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me

```
import os

op = os.path

def fileRead(mydir):
    data = {}
    root = set()
    for i in os.listdir(mydir):
        path = op.join(mydir, i)
        print(path)
        if op.isfile(path):
            data.setdefault(i, set())
            root.add(op.relpath(mydir).replace("\\", "/"))
            data[i] = root
        else:
            data.update(fileRead(path))
    return data


d = fileRead("c:\python32\programas")
print(d)
```

Still I am not sure why you use the set root. I think the purpose is to keep all the directories when you have the same file in two directories. But it doesnt work: each update deletes the stored values for repeated keys (file names).

Here you have a working code, using a defaultdict /you can do the same with an ordinary dictionary (as in your code) but using defauldict you dont need to check if a key has been initialized before:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict
op = os.path

def fileRead(mydir):
    data = defaultdict(list)
    for i in os.listdir(mydir):
        path = op.join(mydir, i)
        print(path)
        if op.isfile(path):
            root = op.relpath(mydir).replace("\\", "/")
            data[i].append(root)
        else:
            for k, v in fileRead(path).items():
                data[k].extend(v)
    return data


d = fileRead("c:\python32\programas")
print(d)
```

---

**Edit:** Relative to the comment from @hughdbrown:

If you update data with `data.update(fileRead(path).items())` you get tthis when calling for `fileRead("c:/python26/programas/pack")` in my computer (now in py26):

> c:/python26/programas/pack\copia.py
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\in pack.py
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\pack2
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\pack2\copia.py
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\pack2\in_pack2.py
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\pack2\pack3
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\pack2\pack3\copia.py
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\pack2\pack3\in3.py
>
> defaultdict( 'list'>, {'in3.py': ['pack/pack2/pack3'], 'copia.py': ['pack/pack2/pack3'],
>   'in pack.py': ['pack'], 'in_pack2.py': ['pack/pack2']})

Note that files that are repeated in several directories (copia.py) only show one of those directories, the deeper one. However all the directories are listed when using:

```
for k, v in fileRead(path).items():  data[k].extend(v)
```

> c:/python26/programas/pack\copia.py
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\in pack.py
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\pack2
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\pack2\copia.py
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\pack2\in_pack2.py
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\pack2\pack3
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\pack2\pack3\copia.py
>   c:/python26/programas/pack\pack2\pack3\in3.py
>
> defaultdict(, {'in3.py': ['pack/pack2/pack3'], 'copia.py': ['pack',  'pack/pack2', 'pack/pack2/pack3'],
>   'in pack.py': ['pack'], 'in_pack2.py': ['pack/pack2']})

Comment: Instead of an explicit loop, try: `data.update(fileRead(path).items())`

Comment: @hughdbrown, I rollbacked to the explicit loop with list extension because otherwise, repeated files in the directory tree do not show the list of different directories. Check my edit in the post.